# Aggregate function & Behavior - Parallel stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Below is an example using,

*aggregate functions*(`filter`/`map`/`sorted`),

&

*behavior*(`this::capitalize`),

&

terminal operation(`forEach`),

with a given stream(`Stream.of(...)`),

```
Stream 
    .of("horatio", "laertes", "Hamlet", ...) 
    .filter(s -> toLowerCase (s.charAt(0)) == 'h')  # aggregate_function(behavior)
    .map(this::capitalize) 
    .sorted() 
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

To not incur race conditions in parallel streams, I learnt that, we need an extra effort to explicitly make *behavior* work without side-effects(stateless), as shown below,

```
String capitalize(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return s;
        return s.substring(0, 1)
            .toUpperCase()
            + s.substring(1)
            .toLowerCase();
```

An *aggregate_function* just applies *behavior* on each element generated from a stream.

---

As element generated from a stream(one at a time), with no non-transient storage,

Without any extra effort, are aggregate functions always pure functions, without any side effects? that does not incur race condition in parallel stream

Comment: You can write `filter/map/sorted` also as stateful, but it's not encouraged and bad practise in functional programming

Comment: @Saravana when data is input from a stream(one at a time), but not your local buffer(list/whatever...), Why would you write aggregate function which is stateful? Aggregate function's job is to just apply *behavior* on that input element coming from stream and forward the output as an input to next aggregate function in pipeline. So, aggregate function clearly looks like a mathematical function

Comment: it depends on how you write the behavior, I meant the aggregate functions can also be written stateful, for example `filter` may depend on class variable which may work as expected in stream may not work same in parallel stream. in your example code its a stateless, either in stream or parallel it will work same as expected.

Comment: and filter/map/sorted are intermediate functions/operations, calling them aggregate functions slightly confusing

Comment: @Saravana Correct. Terminal operations are mostly state ful(like `reduce()`/ `collect()`/..). Terminology is *Input stream* -> *aggregate_function* -> *Terminal_operation*. Teminal operation is different from aggregate function, because each operation in terminal_operation actually triggers operation in aggregate function.

Comment: it again depends how you implement reduce & collect, you can write terminal operations also stateful (bad)

Comment: @Saravana As I said in query, we need extra effort to implement terminal_operation, stateless, unlike implementing aggregate function. This is the actual question to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a key point of the Stream API that all operations support correct parallel processing as long as your behavioral parameters meet the criteria. Or, as [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) states:

> #### Parallelism
>
> Processing elements with an explicit for-loop is inherently serial. Streams facilitate parallel execution by reframing the computation as a pipeline of aggregate operations, rather than as imperative operations on each individual element. All streams operations can execute either in serial or in parallel.
>
> …
>
> Except for operations identified as explicitly nondeterministic, such as `findAny()`, whether a stream executes sequentially or in parallel should not change the result of the computation.
>
> Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior, which are often lambda expressions. To preserve correct behavior, these *behavioral parameters* must be *non-interfering*, and in most cases must be *stateless*. Such parameters are always instances of a functional interface such as Function, and are often lambda expressions or method references.

Note that the term *aggregate operation* is more general, applying to the entire stream operation, including intermediate operations and the terminal operation. What has been said about `map` and `filter`, applies to `reduce` as well; the reduction function should be side effect free and stateless. Note that while `collect` incorporates mutable state, it’s local and still meets the *non-interference* criteria. From the outside, you can still view a `collect` operation is-if stateless.

You have to look at the specific terminal operation’s documentation to find out how a parallel execution might affect the outcome, like the mentioned difference between `findFirst` and `findAny`. In your case [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is problematic, as it may invoke the consumer unordered and concurrently, so there is no guaranty that the elements are printed in the order imposed by the preceding `sorted` step. You should use `forEachOrdered` here.

By the way, you could make your `capitalize` method `static` to emphasize that it doesn’t depend on the state of the `this` instance. Or simplify it to a lambda expression,
`s -> s.isEmpty()? s: s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase()`

Comment: applies to `reduce` as well? Generally Parallelism is applied on intermediate operations but not on terminal operations.  Isn't it?

Comment: Of course, terminal operation run in parallel as well. That’s why the reduction function is required to be [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity). Try `IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel().boxed().reduce("", (s,i) -> Thread.currentThread().getName(), (a,b)->a+" "+b)`…